# python similarity and replace function not work

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list of cities with bad insertion. I tried to write a function to solve this problem by finding the similarity between two stings. I made only the first step for ratio, but did not replace anything:

```
def similar(a, b):  
      SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
        if SequenceMatcher>=60:
          data_city['CITY'].replace('a','b',inplace=True)
          print a
```

Comment: Your code is not formatted. As shown, you will get errors just from the indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Don't quote variable names.

```
....replace('a','b', ...
```

Replaces the **letter** 'a' with the letter 'b', I.e. `apple` to `bpple`